# Tensorflow adding floats gives additional digits

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision

So I was wondering why I do not get the sum of the two floats below, when adding them. Depending on the length of the float and whether there is a non zero digit before the point, the result has either an added or substracted additional digit or they just do not get added. The code below for example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    a = tf.Variable(1, name="Var_a")
    dx = tf.Variable(1.33333, name='dx')
    dt = tf.Variable(5e-10, name='dt')
    dz = tf.Variable(1.0, name='dz')


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        a = dt+dx
        a = a-dz
        print dx.eval()
        print dt.eval()
        print (dt+dx).eval()
        print (dx+dt).eval()
        print a.eval()
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tensorlog")
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

gives the following result:

```
>>>1.33333
>>>5e-10
>>>1.33333
>>>1.33333
>>>0.33333004
```

So the addition did not happen and the subtraction does not give a right result either. Thanks in advance for any ideas on this.

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow variables are 32 bit floats by default, and they do not have enough precision to track the difference `dt`, which is too small in relation to the rest of values. Use `dtype=tf.float64` to increase the precision and you will see the correct results:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    a = tf.Variable(1, name="Var_a", dtype=tf.float64)
    dx = tf.Variable(1.33333, name='dx', dtype=tf.float64)
    dt = tf.Variable(5e-10, name='dt', dtype=tf.float64)
    dz = tf.Variable(1.0, name='dz', dtype=tf.float64)


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        a = dt+dx
        a = a-dz
        print dx.eval()
        print dt.eval()
        print (dt+dx).eval()
        print (dx+dt).eval()
        print a.eval()
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tensorlog")
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

Output:

```
1.33333
5e-10
1.3333300005
1.3333300005
0.33333000049999995
```

Note however that using `tf.float64` instead of `tf.float32` values comes at a cost in terms of memory and time, so use `tf.float64` only when you really require high precision. In general, 32-bit float values are precise to about 7 decimal places while 64-bit float values are precise to about 15 decimal places.